# How to create multidimensional space of points in R

Tags: r

I created one dimensional array of random numbers between 0 and 1 using

`myData <-  runif(1000, 0.0, 1.0);`

How can I create an n dimensional array of 1000 nodes. for example a 10 dimensional random points

Comment: `sapply(1:10, function(i) runif(1000))`? I suppose. It returns a matrix and you can consider each row as a 10 dimensional random point, each column to be one dimension.

Comment: That's it! Thanks.

Comment: How can I access single elements of each row?  row 1000 is :  [1000,] 0.721261917 0.2923419087 0.4572993780

Comment: `[1000, 1]` doesn't work?

Comment: If what @Psidom has suggested is what you are after, then can I suggest a clarification of the question.  You asked for how to make an n-dimensional array, which I explained in my answer. But this is  apparently *not* what you actually wanted. It seems what you actually want is a 2-dimensional array of M points in N-space (i.e. an MxN matrix).

Comment: Yes I was looking for n dimensional space.

Answer (score 0):

The function `array()` will create an array of arbitrary number of dimensions.  The `dim` argument specifies the dimensions.  So, to create an array of 1000 points in a 10x10x10 array, we use

```
a <- array(runif(1000), dim=c(10,10,10))
```

This can be extrapolated to any number of dimensions you wish.

For example

```
a <- array(runif(1000), dim=c(2,2,2,5,5,5))
```

creates a 6 dimensional array with 1000 (=2*2*2*5*5*5) points.  There is no way to decompose 1000 points into a 10 dimensional array, unless some of the dimensions have length 1.

To access values of the array, you can use standard subsetting with `[ ]`, and specify the correct number of dimensions within the brackets.  E.g.

```
a[1,2,1,5,3,2]
# [1] 0.3232738
```

It is worth noting that a `matrix` in R is simply a special case of an `array` with two dimensions.